# How to create a blueprint that extends the volume(like physic volume) in UE5?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I'm looking for a way to create a blueprint that extends the volume. I tried to create a C++ class that extends the volume. And I can create a blueprint that extends my custom volume c++ class. But the blueprint can not compile. Here is the error.

```
Default_MyVolume_c is not valid. please check mapcheck log.
```

And then, I can't change the brush shape in the blueprint. It will crash.
In another way, luckily I can create my custom volume by C++ class from the **Volumes** tab on the **Place Actors** panel.
I'm trying to find a way to create the blueprint for the level designer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old, but you have to override `ShouldCheckCollisionComponentForErrors()` but also use `UActorFactory::CreateBrushForVolumeActor()` to create the brush. The easiest way to do this is to create an Editor module and create an actor factory for your volume, extending `UActorFactoryBoxVolume`.